# Pocket PC development Mobile 5.0 Symbol MC70

Tags: pocketpc, symbols

I need to create app for a Symbol MC70 device running Windows Mobile 5.0

I did some searching for a few hours. Where can I get information on

- Pocket PC development for Windows Mobile 5.0 (MS site on has for Mobile 6.0)
- Development for this particular device (Symbol MC70)

I am running VISUAL Studio 2008 TS.

I downloaded the EMDK.NET from symbol. I created a simple Smart Client test app and able to run it in the VS emulator. I can't seem to find any information on how to deploy to the device.

I do not know where to start. Any leads at all will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EMDK.NET has everything needed.